# Vaadin: How do I display data from a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, vaadin

I'm developing a Vaadin Flow (version 14.1) app and I have this issue, I don't get it to connect directly with MySQL database.

I have set up the JDBC connection with maven, I've also created a singleton class I call Datasource where I store my values and methods. However right now it only has one as I'm testing this, this is what I want to do:

- Click on a button on the app and update a label

Here's the button click listener:

```
button.addClickListener(click -> {
        label.setText(Datasource.getInstance().getUsername());
    });
```

Here's the Datasource class method:

```
public String getUsername() {
    String username = "QUERY-FAILED";

    try {
        start();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from names");

        rs.next();
        username = rs.getString(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }

    return username;
}
```

But the label doesn't update, if I comment the try block it updates to QUERY-FAILED which is the string I put to test if it failed, but if it isn't commented the label just stays the same.

I also tried to add a main method to the Datasource class and run it as a Java application, and the method works fine, it does return a string with the username. So I'm guessing I'm stuck somewhere in between the connection with the vaadin app. Also, If I try to get the username String in my vaadin app when I'm starting the app (and not with a click listener) I got an long stack of errors with the Datasource indicating a nullpointerexception here:

```
statement = conn.createStatement();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Vaadin?

Comment: What does rs.getString(1) return when you debug?

Comment: The last one, Vaadin flow @BasilBourque

Comment: @ReneAlvarenga Post such details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. I did so for you just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot spot any problem with your code. But I can provide an entire working example app for you to compare

My example app goes along the lines laid out in your Question's code. A Vaadin `Button` performs a database query using a `DataSource` object from a table of user names. The value from the first row found is displayed in a Vaadin `Label` widget on the web page.

[image]

This app was built and run with Vaadin 14.1.5 using a "Plain Java Servlet" flavor of a starter project [provided by the Vaadin.com site](https://vaadin.com/start/latest). Running on macOS Mojave with the bundled Jetty web container.

My only changes to their Maven POM file was to change to Java version 13, and to add a dependency for [*H2 Database Engine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) to make this a self-contained example using an in-memory database.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>
```

I used the hook for Vaadin starting, to establish my [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object and initialize the database. [Following the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html), nested in the `resources` folder, I created folders `META-INF` > `services`. Per the [Java SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) facility, there I created a file named `com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServiceInitListener` containing a single line to specify the name of my class that implements the interface named in the name of this file:

```
work.basil.example.ApplicationServiceInitListener
```

That is, my `ApplicationServiceInitListener` class implement the Vaadin interface `VaadinServiceInitListener`. My class will be automatically instantiated and its method invoked via that Java SPI facility when my Vaadin web app launches.

My `ApplicationServiceInitListener` class:

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceInitEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServiceInitListener;
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

public class ApplicationServiceInitListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener
{
    @Override
    public void serviceInit ( ServiceInitEvent serviceInitEvent )
    {
        System.out.println( "DEBUG Running `serviceInit` of " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() );

        // Database work.
        prepareDataSource();
        App.INSTANCE.provideDatabase().initializeDatabase();
    }

    private void prepareDataSource ( )
    {
        JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:demo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
        App.INSTANCE.rememberDataSource( ds );
    }
}
```

That class calls my `App` class which acts as a sort of [service locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). Designed as a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) via [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
package work.basil.example;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Objects;

public enum App
{
    INSTANCE;

    // -------|  DataSource  |---------------------------------
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource provideDataSource ( )
    {
        return this.dataSource;
    }

    public void rememberDataSource ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        this.dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( dataSource );
    }


    // -------|  Database  |---------------------------------
    private Database database;

    public Database provideDatabase ( )
    {
        return new Database();
    }
}
```

That class calls my `Database` class. In real work, `Database` would be an interface with various concrete implementations for testing versus deployment. I ignored that here for demonstration purposes.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Database
{
    public String getFirstUserName ( )
    {
        String userName = "QUERY-FAILED";

        String newline = "\n";
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append( "SELECT name_ from  user_ ; " ).append( newline );
        System.out.println( "sql = " + sql );
        try (
                Connection conn = App.INSTANCE.provideDataSource().getConnection() ;
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement() ;
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( sql.toString() ) ;
        )
        {
            while ( resultSet.next() )
            {
                userName = resultSet.getString( "name_" );
                break; // Go no further. We need only the first row found.
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return userName;
    }

    public void initializeDatabase ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "DEBUG Running `initializeDatabase` of " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() );
        String newline = "\n";

        // Create table.
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append( "CREATE TABLE user_ ( " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( "pkey_ IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , " ).append( newline );  // `identity` = auto-incrementing long integer.
        sql.append( "name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( ") " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( ";" ).append( newline );
        System.out.println( "sql = " + sql );
        try (
                Connection conn = App.INSTANCE.provideDataSource().getConnection() ;
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement() ;
        )
        {
            statement.executeUpdate( sql.toString() );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("DEBUG Finished `CREATE TABLE` statement.");

        // Populate table.
        sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append( "INSERT INTO user_ ( name_ ) " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( "VALUES " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( "( 'Alice' ) , " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( "( 'Bob' ) , " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( "( 'Carol' ) " ).append( newline );
        sql.append( ";" ).append( newline );
        System.out.println( "sql = " + sql );
        try (
                Connection conn = App.INSTANCE.provideDataSource().getConnection() ;
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement() ;
        )
        {
            int rowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate( sql.toString() );
            System.out.println( "DEBUG Inserted rows into name_ table: " + rowsAffected );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("DEBUG Finished `INSERT` statement.");
    }
}
```

And lastly, the `MainView` class. I disable the `@PWA` annotation as we are not using that feature for progressive web apps.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
//@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    private Label label;
    private Button button;

    public MainView ( )
    {
        // Widgets
        this.label = new Label( "User: ?" );
        this.button = new Button(
                "Get user" ,
                event -> {
                    Notification.show( "Getting user." );
                    String userName = App.INSTANCE.provideDatabase().getFirstUserName();
                    this.label.setText( "User: " + userName );
                }
        );
        add( button );

        // Arrange
        this.add( label , button );
    }
}
```

Comment: jesus christ... this was the issue somehow...

String userName = App.INSTANCE.provideDatabase().getFirstUserName();
                    this.label.setText( "User: " + userName );

you added a string to get the name, then use the string in the label .setText method, I've tried that and works perfectly... somehow it doesn't update if the Datasource method isn't retrieved with a String object, thanks man!!... you got any idea why that happens though?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the `ResultSet rs` actually has results. When calling `rs.next()`, look if it returns false. [How to check if ResultSet is empty](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-check-if-resultset-is-empty-in-Java-JDBC.html)

```
public String getUsername() {
    String username = "QUERY-FAILED";

    try {
        start();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select userName from names");

        if(rs.next() != false){
            username = rs.getString(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }

    return username;
}
```

Another thing I noticed is that from the query `select * from names`, one cannot be sure that the userName attribute is the first column, which you are reading with `rs.getString(1)`. Make sure to write your query more precise to avoid hard-to-find bugs: `select userName from names`; Do this even if the table only has one column, because what if somebody prepended another column? it could break your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kscherrer! Yes, the resultset does return a string which is the username, but only when the class is running as a java application, it doesn't do anything if it's run in the vaadin application, oh and this isn't the final implementation for my app, it's just testing at the moment, I'll build queries with stringbuilder to avoid injections for the final implementation, at the moment it's just for small testing to check if everything's working okay before moving forward